# How do I repair a wall after mild water damage?

Tags: drywall, repainting

Some water got in my wall near a window when it was raining (the window shade had previously put a nick on the window sill corner exposing the drywall). The water got in behind some of the paint and created a bubble that I peeled off. I scraped away all the loose paint and drywall with a flathead, then sanded a little bit. I'm wondering if I need to spackle and/or prime before I try painting over the exposed area?

The paint is from Benjamin Moore.

Here are some photos to better explain the damage:

[image: Drywall damage]
[image]

Comment: before doing as [Tester101 says below](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/8052/wall-and-paint-repair-after-slight-water-damage/8061#8061), have you fixed the problem that allowed the water to get in, in the first place?

Comment: The problem was leaving the window open while it raining :)

Comment: Ok! then you should be "golden" to proceed as per [Tester101 below answer](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/8052/wall-and-paint-repair-after-slight-water-damage/8061#8061) :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Patch the holes, prime, then paint.

Usually when I patch walls I end up priming and painting the entire wall, it's more work but I find it looks much better when I'm done.

Comment: That makes sense. I really don't want to sand and prime the entire wall for such a small repair though. I will try as you suggest and see if I can get it to look decent. Thanks.